# Two dropdowns in a dialog box (Android)

Tags: gui-design, android

We have a pop dialog in our desktop solution where you need to select values from 2 dropdowns and click OK.

Now I want a similar thing for our Android solution.

I'm not sure because in case of Android it will open a dialog on top of a dialog while selecting values from "Spinners".

Will this violate some design guidelines, or is there a better display this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a nice solution which will work perfectly in my case:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Why not picker wheel + Button ?

It's easy to use.

some Examples

photo 
[Percolator app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/percolator/id385454903)

finance
[MoneyIQ app](http://www.moneyiqapp.com/features)

Android also available.
[How to](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-wheel-picker-example.html)

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work in Android. Cos both of these are Iphone apps. N I'm looking for a solution in Android where you have spinners.

Comment: @daniel-eckmann: Please don't use short URLs. This isn't Twitter & we have plenty of space.

Answer (score -1):

[image: 3 spinners]

[Voip Bandwidth Calculator](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.facadesoft.voipbwcalc&hl=en)

[image]

Stackoverflow question ["How to create a popup window with spinner for android?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075371/how-to-create-a-popup-window-with-spinner-for-android)

Comment: This shows many dropdowns on a normal page (activity). In my case the layout itself is a dialog box, so my question was will it make sense to open another dialog box (showing the list of options), on top of a dialog box.